# mysql-test-run: *** ERROR: Could not find any

Tags: mysql

I  got server with `mysql 5.0`, it used to work I had configuration issue and now I have this error if you can please give me some insights

```
mysql-test-run: *** ERROR: Could not find any of /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/release/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/relwithdebinfo/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/debug/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/release/mysqld-debug /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/relwithdebinfo/mysqld-debug /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/debug/mysqld-debug /root/mysql-5.0.91/sql/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/client/mysqld-max-nt /root/mysql-5.0.91/client/mysqld-max /root/mysql-5.0.91/client/mysqld-nt /root/mysql-5.0.91/client/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/client/mysqld-debug /root/mysql-5.0.91/client/mysqld-max /root/mysql-5.0.91/libexec/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/bin/mysqld /root/mysql-5.0.91/sbin/mysqld
make: *** [test-ns] Error 1
```

Im on `centos 6x` with running `apache 2.2`

Comment: How did you install MySQL-5.0? Normally you'd run mysql-test-run not as a root user (some tests/mtr will complain) and run it from the top level install (aka `mysql-test/mtr`)

Comment: From the tar package ./configure and all else ,I did it from a site of geekz and is same code I get same errors when installing direct from package